# httpbasic + apikey and multitenancy

Tags: multi-tenant, basic-authentication

I'm about to implement httpbasic + apikey authentication with multitenancy.
What I mean... I'd like to create procedure with input parameters for username, password and apikey, so that users could use it with their own credentials, not only with stored default creds.

Below is how it works in sql without multitenancy.

```
EXEC SYSADMIN.createConnection("name" => 'webservice1',  "jbossCLITemplateName" => 'name1',  "connectionOrResourceAdapterProperties" =>  'EndPoint=https://api.example.com/api/,SecurityType=HTTPBasic,AuthUserName=[EMAIL]',  "encryptedProperties" => 'AuthPassword=[PASSWORD]') ;;

EXEC SYSADMIN.createDataSource("name" => 'webservice1',  "translator" => 'name1', "modelProperties" => '',  "translatorProperties" => '', "encryptedModelProperties" => '',  "encryptedTranslatorProperties" => '') ;;

exec  webservice1.invokeHTTP(endpoint=>'2.0/checks',requestHeaders=>  App-Key: myapikey1  ,action=>'GET',requestContentType=>'application/xml')
```

Now I'm trying to create connection without authusername and authpassword and it does work

```
EXEC SYSADMIN.createConnection("name" => 'webservice1',  "jbossCLITemplateName" => 'name1',  "connectionOrResourceAdapterProperties" =>  'EndPoint=https://api.example.com/api/,SecurityType=HTTPBasic') ;;

EXEC SYSADMIN.createDataSource("name" => 'webservice1',  "translator" => 'name1', "modelProperties" => '',  "translatorProperties" => '', "encryptedModelProperties" => '',  "encryptedTranslatorProperties" => '') ;;
```

but then I'm trying to call my webservice with credentials entered manually

```
exec  webservice1.invokeHTTP(endpoint=>'2.0/checks',requestHeaders=>  AuthUserName: user1 || AuthPassword: pass1 || App-Key:  myapikey1,action=>'GET',requestContentType=>'application/xml')
```

and receive error:

> Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://api.example.com/api//2.0/test1** http error stream***{"error":{"statuscode":401,"statusdesc":" Unauthorized","errormessage":"User credentials missing"}}

How do I pass username and password for httpbasic auth properly without need to recreate the connection for different user?
Please advise.

Comment: For http basic 
x = Base64 encoding of username:password 
Header Name : Authorization
Header Value : Basic x

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest that despite using the custom basic authorization header, more details should be included like the domain, time stamp, computed signature of the headers so that the validity of the headers and also possibly avoid request replay attacks.

AWS signature model
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-authenticating-requests.html